# Java Regex, filter Document for list of Signalwords and Stopwords

Tags: java, regex, keyword, prefix

I want to filter a document for specific keywords, e.g:

```
ausschreibungs id|ausschreibungs-id|ausschreibungsid|ausschreibungsnummer|chiffre nummer|chiffre-nummer|chiffrenr.|chiffre nr.|chiffre-nr.|chiffrenummer|chiffre code|chiffre-code|chiffrecode|chiffre|job-id|job-nr.|job-nr|job id|job nr.|jobnummer|jobnr.|jobid|jobcode|job nr.|ziffer|kennziffer|kennz.|referenz code|referenz-code|referenzcode|ref. nr.|ref. id|ref id|ref.id|ref.-nr.|ref.- nr.|referenz nummer|referenznummer|referenz nr.|referenz-nr.|referenznr.|referenz|referenznummer der stelle|id#|id #|stellenausschreibung nr.|stellenausschreibung nr|stellenausschreibungs nr.|stellenausschreibungs-nr.|stellenausschreibungsnr.|stellenangebots id|stellenangebots-id|stellenangebotsid|stellen id|stellen-id|stellenid|stellenreferenz|stellen-referenz|ref.|st.nr.|stellennumer|st.-nr.|st. nr.|kenn-nr.|positionsnummer|kennwort|stellenkey|stellencode|job-referenzcode|bewerbungskennziffer|projekt id|projekt-id|reference number|reference no.|reference code|job code|job id|job vacancy no.|job-ad-number|auto req id|job ref|kennziffer|
```

Usually, after those keyword, a weird String with decimals, special chars or alphabet chars is expected, like "AE_0394-33" or similar, it could be anything also normal words etc... But usually, decimal numbers appear very often (or at least once) in that string...

I would like to filter documents based on everything that comes after that list of possible signal-keywords (followed by a white-space and then the weird string followed by another whitespace). The matching string that I want to filter is in general a whole string without whitespaces in between.

I have also a list of Stopwords, where my idea was, that I delete all words or the sentence following those stopwords to decrease the candidate number of possible matches, until a "." comes (that finishes the sentence).

Those stopwords list could be:

```
der|des|das|die|dem|den|ein|eine|diese|diese|dieser|es|sie|wir|unser|ihr|dein|nr|und|hier|oder|wie|an|angeben|mitteilen|id|nicht|einsatzort|bereit|vorzugsweise|ausschließlich|nummer|hiermit|für|auf|was|code|nr.|#||bzw.|via|von|zu|Anzahl|zum|zur|bis|ab|gerne||job|+49|tel|telefon|fax|plz|hausnr.|hausnummer|email|e-mail|veröffentlichung|veroeffentlichung|
```

I just have a problem formulating that regex to take into account the words following the keywords, and otherwise around, to filter those words or sentences out that follow the stopwords...

I was thinking about a list of prefix stopwords or keywords, and then I either take one single word-boundary following the keyword, or I take a whole bunch of words until a decimal point "." arises...

I was trying a regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/peHT1v/1

for keywords, but I have no idea how I can mark those words as prefix list of alternate single words, followed by another word?

E.g: 
`[list, of , keywords] *whitespace* \s+(.*)\s+` <- where `(\s+.*\s+)` is my word boundary capturing group matching string or even a whole sentence until "." follows

I give an additional Example:

```
Referenznummer: INDUSTRY Kontakt: ZAsdfsdfS Herr Andrafgdh Neue Str. 7 21244 Buchholz +42341 22322 mdjob.bu44lz@zaqusssis.de Stellenanzeige teilen: Jetzt online bewerben! oder bewerben Sie sich mit
```

I want to have `INDUSTRY` because its followed by the keyword "Referenznummer"

```
"Geben Sie bei Ihrer Bewerbung die Stellenreferenz und die Stellenbezeichnung an!\n" + 
"Stellenreferenz:   21533448-JOtest\n" +
```

I want `21533448-JOtest` because its followed by some keyword "Stellenreferenz"

```
Stellenausschreibung Nr. PD-666/19
```

I'd like `PD-666/19`

```
Parkwe 103 33 /  sss968 Kasn 
            "FFFF\r\n" 
            "E-Mail: Test.Ticfffsssis-Jsdf741@drbsdfil.deeddilProtedddctor.adasdilto(\"ep_5b0224b6\", 1); 
            "Tel: (33 21) 23 42 117-3 \r\n" + 

            "Jetzt bewerben
            "  2018-12-04 nicht-medsdfs asfal";
```

I would like nothing, or even delete the whole sentence that follows those stopwords like "Tel", and "E-Mail", to make the filtering of other keywords more easier/ clear...

Comment: If you need to get a non-whitespace char chunk of text after  a list of keywords, capture it: `(?:your|stopwords|here)\s+(\S+)`.

Comment: Your edit is very unclear: what do you mean by *even a whole sentence until "." follows*? If you need to get all up to the first `.`, use `(?:your|stopwords|here)\s+([^.]+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I would use look behind and word boundary `(?<=your|stopwords|here)\b+(\S+)`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher No need to use lookbehinds as overlapping matches are not expected, and in Java code you will still have to get the string value from a `.group()`. Besides, `\b` is a zero-width assertion, `(?<=your|stopwords|here)\b+(\S+)` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your update. you may use

```
(?:Stellenreferenz:|Referenznummer:|Stellenausschreibung Nr\.)\s*(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CvmAa6/3)

**Details**

- `(?:Stellenreferenz:|Referenznummer:|Stellenausschreibung Nr\.)` - a non-capturing group matching any of the stop words you define
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars.

[Java test](https://ideone.com/eUrIoU):

```
String s = "Referenznummer: INDUSTRY Kontakt: ZAsdfsdfS Herr Andrafgdh Neue Str. 7 21244 Buchholz +42341 22322 mdjob.bu44lz@zaqusssis.de Stellenanzeige teilen: Jetzt online bewerben! oder bewerben Sie sich mit\n" +
                "Geben Sie bei Ihrer Bewerbung die Stellenreferenz und die Stellenbezeichnung an! \n" +
                "Stellenreferenz:   21533448-JOtest\n\n" +
                "Stellenausschreibung Nr. PD-666/19";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:Stellenreferenz:|Referenznummer:|Stellenausschreibung Nr\\.)\\s*(\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Output:

```
INDUSTRY
21533448-JOtest
PD-666/19
```

Comment: thanks that worked, and for excluding text after some keywords, how would I do it ? With (?!list|of|words)(\S+) and replaceAll(group(0),"") ?

Comment: @user2774480 Replace `\\s*(\\S+)` with `\\s*+(?!(?:your|exceptions|here)(?!\\S))(\\S+)`

Comment: thanks, but somehow that didnt work so well... consider this sentence: "Institut Berlin kennziffer 19-34-8 Abbestraße 2-122345" I want to catch all after keyword "kennziffer", but I want to break or replace everything when keyword "straße" comes

Comment: yes similar to that but it should ignore the whole word that contains "straße" or any other of the stopwords

Comment: @user2774480 Ok, so you need `"(?U)(?:Stellenreferenz:|Referenznummer:|Stellenausschreibung Nr\\.|kennziffer)\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\w*straße)"` in Java

Comment: Yup, that worked quite well, I adapted it a bit: `(?U)(?:Stellenreferenz:|Referenznummer:|Stellenausschreibung Nr\.|kennziffer)\s*(.*)(\s*)(?=\w*straße|email|adresse)  for Strings like this: Institut Berlin kennziffer 19-34-8 Abbestraße 2-122345 Referenznummer: 394932-S93_3-W Test 234234email 39420394`

Comment: @user2774480 The greedy quantifier will grab all you expected `\s*` would grab. Replace `(.*)(\s*)(?=\w*` with `(.*)(?=\b\w*`, then `trim` the results before using.

Comment: ok thanks that worked, can you maybe show me how to filter for words coming after those signal Words and that have as prefix only uppercase-letters followed by space, eighter before or after their word because they belong together..  e.g : `kennziffer: ST 38_dof-33 TT` should be found but not something like: `kennziffer st 934_df39  tt` there, only the `934_df39` is relevant